# How to read a display name from a DLL?

Tags: c#, dll, registry

In the registry and in theme files you'll notice a lot of references to DLLs when it comes to display names.

For example:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\AppEvents\Schemes\Apps\.Default]
@="Windows"
"DispFileName"="@mmres.dll,-5856"
```

I've opened the mmres.dll file in PE Explorer, but I don't see any display names.

How can I retrieve the actuale display name behind the **@mmres.dll,-5856** reference in C#?
How can I do this efficiently for many references?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're looking for GetFileVersionInfoEx (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646981(VS.85).aspx)